# SQL deduplicate from two columns

Tags: sql, duplicates, ignore-duplicates

I've been struggling with this for quite some time but i just can't figure it out.

I have a table with 3 columns. 2 columns containing names and the third one containing the Damerau Levensthein distance ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance ) between those names.

each column has includes every single name, that means all the names present in the autor1 column are present in the autor2 column as well. as a result i have twice the rows needed, just with the autor1 and autor2 columns swapped.

as an example, row 3 equals to row 1 just with the autor columns swapped, the same goes for 2-4. how would i formulate a query that omits those "duplicates"? 
id-|------autor1----|------autor2-----| dld
1 -| Abel, Gustav -| Abel, Gustave | 1
2 -| Abel, Gustav -| Abele, Gustav | 1
3 -| Abel, Gustave| Abel, Gustav --| 1
4 -| Abele, Gustav | Abel, Gustav -| 1

to 
|------autor1----|------autor2-----| dld
| Abel, Gustav -| Abel, Gustave | 1
| Abel, Gustav -| Abele, Gustav | 1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `NOT EXISTS` works on all DBMS's I know of. The *complexity* of this is to not forget to include a clause on `id`. Without it, nothing would be returned.

```
SELECT *
FROM   YourTable yto
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT  *
         FROM    YourTable yti
         WHERE   yti.autor2 = yto.autor1
                 AND yti.id > yto.id
       )
```

**Edit**

step by step, following is a breakdown of the logic behind the statement

1. Get the first record (`ID = 1`)
2. Is there a record where `ID > 1` and `autor1 = autor2` (Yes, ID 3) -> **Ignore**
3. Get the next record (`ID = 2`)
4. Is there a record where `ID > 2` and `autor1 = autor2` (Yes, ID 4) -> **Ignore**
5. Get the next record (`ID = 3`)
6. Is there a record where `ID > 3` and `autor1 = autor2` (No) -> **Include**
7. Get the next record (`ID = 4`)
8. Is there a record where `ID > 4` and `autor1 = autor2` (No) -> **Include**

Comment: you're a genius. although i'm afraid i don't fully understand how the "greater-than" magic works.

Comment: @lightxx - I've added a breakdown of the logic behind the statement. Hopefully, it clears things up a bit.

Comment: I think the part which is `AND yti.id > yto.id`, saved my life. This prevents the duplication Thanks for the solution.